# Should I be doing work inthe loop from which i am taking Input in C++ competitive Programming

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, c++17, stdvector

I am fairly new to competitive programming with c++ and till now I have always tried to keep my input loops separate from the rest of the code. Because I used to think the data stream should be processed separately to optimize for speed but recently on one question I saw that the time taken to run n cases got reduced by a small factor when the work was combined into the same loop.

here is the code with the loops separated out.

```
vector<int> a(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin>>a[i];
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) a[i] = a[i]+a[i-1];
```

here is the code for the combined

```
vector<int> a(n);
int sum = 0;
int x;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   cin>>x;
   sum += x;
   a[i] = sum ;
}
```

Which of these is faster in general and why ??

Also
Does input loop get counted in the overall space complexity of the code?

Comment: Loops generally don't get involved in space complexity, just time complexity. If you allocate storage in that loop, you'll have a problem, but if you're allocating storage in a loop , the time costs of the allocation will probably kill you in a competition.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you have no control over how your code is compiled on these "competitive websites".  Do these sites tell you the compiler version and whether optimization flags are used?  An optimizing compiler may very well turn that first example into something looking like the second example.

Comment: Two sequential loops won't increase the time complexity because you's wind up with O(2n) and constants are discarded. It does mean more code (so more room for screw-ups) and possibly a noticeable hit to real world performance in some cases. I'd write one loop.

Comment: All that said, usually the winner in these competitions is the coder who realized the sneaky trick that eliminated the need for the loop in the first place.

Comment: And of course a question like this begs the counter-question: "Why don't you time it and find out?" Reality is the final arbiter. As Paul pointed out above, the compiler could do some really off-the-wall optimization and merge the loops for you. [See the As-If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)

Comment: Both code might have very less or no time complexity difference and so must be ignored. Also if u want very detailed complexity analysis u should research first about each small operations.

Answer (score 3):

> Which of these is faster in general and why ??

I'd expect the second version to be faster for larger amounts of data.

The reason is caches. If the data is too large to fit in the cache, then (assuming a typical "least recently used" eviction policy) for the first version the first elements of the array will be evicted from the cache to make room for the later/last elements of the array in the first loop; causing a huge amount of cache misses for the second loop.

Of course for modern CPUs/computers there are many caches (e.g. L1, L2, L3, then TLBs). This results in many different "amounts of data" that reduce the performance of the first version. In other words, for small amounts of data the performance may be similar, for "between 64 KiB and 256 KiB of data" the performance of the first version might be twice as bad, for "between 256 KiB and 8 MiB of data" the performance of the first version might be 4 times as bad, and so on.

Note that (in theory) a compiler may optimize both to be the same; and in a perfect world (where compilers are ideal) there'd be no point having competitive programming competitions because the compiler will produce the same output regardless of what the programmer writes. Unfortunately compilers are nowhere near perfect;  and for competitions optimizations may have been disabled to increase the emphasis on the programmer's skill.